# Failed to load resources, status 404 gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I'm trying to deploying my react app, using gh pages.
But i'm getting error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Can someone please help me with resolving this.

I tried to check the paths mentioned in files, if they seem correct, but couldn't identify if something was wrong with them.

Link of the repo
https://github.com/divyabaheti101/ETB-react-1-todo-list/tree/main